# Java String with divergent "length"

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have the following String in Java

```
String test = "this string has been changed for test purposes so that it can be clearly seen how many chars it has without exposing sensible information testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaString ends here";
```

When I count its length on the `.jsp` using JavaScript it shows me 1000 characters as expected (0 to 999). But when I go to the `.action` class in the Java code and use

```
test.length();
```

It returns 1007.

I used an online diff and count tool between the "inspected" string from the debug code and the input string from the jsp. But it turns out the counter gave me a value of 1000 an the diff tool showed me that the two Strings were identical.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Non printable characters.

Comment: you mean like "enter" and "tab" or other special characters?

Comment: more things like `\0` that don't actually print. You'd notice a newline or a tab.

Comment: I don't think that might be the issue, the only "different" char is an "°" and it only appears once.

Comment: I can also count only 1000 chars, so can my Java. So any non-printable characters or whatever must have been lost in pasting into the question.

Comment: I'll check on that again. Thank you very much.

Comment: I checked it again and it gave me 7 occurrences of the char CR LF at a couple lines. I believe that is the issue, now I just have to remove them. Thank you very much. And it also only happens if data is pasted on the field.